# Top (numeric / special symbol) keys on HP 15-b010tx regularly stop working. (Win 8.1 Pro)

Tags: laptop, windows-8.1, keyboard

I am sure this query has been found and answered elsewhere, but damned if I can find it.

I am using an HP 15-b010tx Sleekbook with Windows 8.1 Pro, all updates regularly applied.

About two weeks ago, I noticed when typing that the top numeric / special symbol keys on the laptop keyboard stopped working - **except for 5, 6, Backspace and "="**

After pressing the "=" key a few times and then Backspace, the keys came alive again and worked - until I started typing using the letters on the keyboard, at which point top row stopped functioning.  Using "=" and backspace didn't work, and I tried using the space bar two or three times, followed by backspace - this worked.

This is now a daily - and frustrating - bug.  To bring the keys alive again, I have to try combinations of "=". Spacebar, Backspace and occassionally the "help" button.  Not every combination works every time.

To cure this I have tried:

- Using a plug in USB keyboard.  **Same error is repeated on this keyboard**.
- deleting keyboard from Device Manager, rebooting and rediscovering keyboard.  **Error reappears after reboot**
- Changing USB wireless mouse. **Error reappears**
- Changing from USB wireless mouse to Microsoft wired mouse. **Error reappears**
- Removing mouse, just using trackpad. **Error reappears.**
- Taking apart and cleaning keyboard contacts. **Error reappears** (*NOTE: Didn't expect this to clear fault, as fault appears on plug-in keyboard, but carried out for the sake of completeness*)

So I am coming to the conclusion it must be a software fault - I suspect a Microsoft update, although no idea which one, purely because nothing else has been loaded onto the machine, and machine has started doing this "out of the blue"

Has anybody else come across this error? I have searched but cannot find this error related to Windows 8.1 - there is a mention of it on this forum applying to Win 10, but caused by software I am not running (Windows 10 Power Toys).

Comment: If it happens even with an external keyboard, the issue is certainly in software or in the main machine's hardware/firmware. It may be time for a reinstallation of Windows to see if it was a rogue piece of software on your machine.

Comment: There is a know printer pool problem introduced in a recent update Windows Update.  You will have to wait until the appropriate Windows 8.1 update is released

Comment: @Ramhound - many thanks for that.  The fact it started about two weeks ago without anything else having been installed is what lead me to suspect an update.  Hope they sort it out soon ...

Comment: I have no idea why I thought this had anything to do with a printer.  I apologize

Comment: @Ramhound Dang!! Back to square 1. Many thanks anyway.  I still think it’s a dodgy update ....